# Как передать List в главный поток?

Tags: android, многопоточность

Есть поток в котором происходит заполнение и генерация List. Нужно его передать в главный поток в адаптер, как это сделать?

```
private class LooperThread extends Thread implements Handler.Callback{

    Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        handler = new Handler(this);
        Looper.loop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
        if(message.what == 0){
            DepositGeneration generation = new DepositGeneration();
            DepositOperations operations = new DepositOperations(generation.setList());
            List<DepositItem> list = operations.sortedList();
            List<BaseProduct> products = DepositFormatter.setProducts(list);

        }
        return true;
    }

    public Handler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }
}
```

Comment: А Вам ведь предлагали `AsyncTask`... Ну, если мы не ищем лёгких путей, то в главном потоке создайте ещё один `Handler` и передайте его сюда через конструктор, `Handler.Callback` пусть реализует `Activity` или кто там у Вас должен принять этот список.  После заполнения списка отправьте его посылкой через новый `Handler` - на той стороне принимайте и делайте с ним что хотите.

Comment: У меня задание использовать старый метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочтите внимательно [документацию](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui)

Если совсем коротко вам надо дождаться завершения `Looper`'а и упаковать ваш лист в `Message`

P.S. Вообще конечно, как предлагает @woesss гораздо проще все это обтяпать с `AsyncTask`